# Execute SQL Stored procedure which calling BCP command inside

Tags: c#, sql-server, sql-server-2012, bcp

I want to call a SQL stored procedure which executes a BCP command inside using C#.

While executing the stored procedure from SQL Server, it generates file on specified location.

But while calling that stored procedure from C# its not generating file.

Below command is in stored procedure `usp_GenerateFile`, and I am trying to execute `usp_GenerateFile` from C# application

```
Select * from ##TransactionsOUT ORDER BY RowID,Z

Set @bcpString = 'bcp "Select Row from ##TransactionsOUT ORDER BY RowID,Z" queryout ' + @FullPath + ' -T -t\t -r\n -c'    

EXEC xp_cmdshell @bcpString ,no_output
```

Comment: How is it not generating the file? Are you getting some kind of error message? If so please edit your question to include the error message - as text.

Comment: Are you logging into the SSMS with exactly the same credentials that the C# process is using?

Comment: `But while calling that stored procedure from C# its not generating file.` It likely is generating the file. But it is _on the SQL Server._ Is that where you are looking?

Comment: What is the _exact_ value of `@FullPath`?

Comment: There is no error , while executing Stored procedure in SSMS its generating file on specified location but while calling Stored procedure using C# its not generating file on specified location.

Comment: full path is D:\TestFiles\file.txt

Comment: @AlwaysLearning yes i am using same credentials,
File is not there on specified path while i am executing SP from Ado.Net code using c#

Comment: So just to confirm: (a) `EXEC xp_cmdshell @bcpString ,no_output` returns immediately but there is no file left behind? or (b) `EXEC xp_cmdshell @bcpString ,no_output` just hangs there and never finishes?

Comment: @AlwaysLearning option (a) is happening
File is not generating and no any error in c# while cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()